# How to change values of an xml file in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Whenever I run the program the xml file simply adds another parts over the original code rather than replacing it.
Here's my files

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<stuff>stuff</stuff>
```

C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        FileStream f = new FileStream(@"C:\ file path", FileMode.Open);
        doc.Load(f);
        doc.SelectSingleNode("stuff").InnerText = "hi";
        doc.Save(f);
    }
```

Resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<stuff>stuff</stuff><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stuff>hi</stuff>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I think it has to do with loading stuff to the stream and assigning it more to the same stream.

Maybe you should do the simple way (that works):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\Temp\Test.xml");
        doc.SelectSingleNode("stuff").InnerText = "hi";
        doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\Test.xml");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

The overload for [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes the filename will achieve what you are looking for. It overwrites the existing file.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        FileStream f = new FileStream(@"C:\file.xml", FileMode.Open);
        doc.Load(f);
        f.Close();
        doc.SelectSingleNode("stuff").InnerText = "hi";
        doc.Save(@"C:\file.xml");
```